# Do English words have a sort of de-facto inherrent gender (or gender stereotype) to them?

Tags: grammar, written-language, pronouns, gender, natural-gender

I apologize in advance if this question goes all over the place, I was just randomly thinking today about gender in the English language.

One thing in English that I find is overlooked is gender in the language.

Many nouns in English have some sort of implied gender or some sort of gender connotation or stereotype attached to them. I wonder how much of this is due to gender stereotypes in our society or actual language rules (if there are any actually written down.) Or remnants of old grammatical gender in English etc. And I wonder if this applies for other languages.

Reminder that I'm literally just a college student who likes grammar and does it as a side hobby. So I may not be completely correct, this is just my interpretation.

In my opinion certain nouns definitely carry a gender stereotype or sound very exclusively gendered.

For example:

A Midwife? Feminine
A Secretary? Feminine
A Knight? Male
A Lumberjack? Male

Some nouns have masculine and feminine forms (I wonder if they would just be considered different words rather than variations? Would this be considered agreement?)

For example:

Priest/Priestess
Actor/Actress
Waiter/Waitress
Fireman/Firewoman

And then we have nouns that can only be attached to one gender such as

Lad
Lesbian
Player (in the dating sense)
Crone
Maiden
A john (in the prostitution sense)

Some words (mostly just French loanwords but a few English words) can "conjugate/agree" (I use that as loosely as possible,) based on gender, but these rules seem to be inconsistently enforced with some people saying it should mandatory and others not even caring or just using one version for all (this definitely seems to be regional in most examples I can think of.)

Fiancé/Fiancée
Blond/Blonde
Confidant/Confidante

Inanimate objects and some animals can also carry gender connotations, I consider this moreso poetic (It is called metaphorical gender and it is personally my favorite feature in English,) it is something interesting to think about.

Ship (female)
The Sun (male)
Cars (Feminine)
Whales (Feminine)
Cats (Feminine)

There are also adjectives that seem to carry gender connotations as well and seem to only really be able to be used with one gender.

Handsome? Male
Catty? Female
Nagging? Female

These sound wrong when used with "the wrong gender" most of the time. Is it  grammatically wrong or logically wrong, and if it is grammatically wrong, then why?

How is changing the gender in another language like French any different?

What makes both of these sentences wrong?

"He works as a waitress at the diner."
"Je mange un pomme."

If one is correct and the other is wrong could someone explain why? The French one doesn't even have its meaning changed while the English one does.

There are definitely certain nouns with gender connotations, this seems to mostly be based on gender stereotypes though rather than an actual grammatical reason (I assume)

Certain adjectives like bossy or nagging are rarely if ever directed towards men. And men are rarely called pretty or fertile. I don't think there are any rules against it but it does sound wrong as a native English speaker.

We have natural gender that isn't always natural "Can you make that baby stop crying, **It's** crying is giving me a headache."

Is gender in every language just a bunch of social rules anyway  it's not like gender has to be a part of English (or even French) people could easily just start saying "Le Pomme" instead of "La Pomme" or start saying "People-kind instead of "Man-kind"

Many people think that English lacking a grammatical gender system means that the language is "genderless" (Which it isn't.)

Most of this was just a rambling of my many ideas but I guess If I had to surmize it into a few questions I would ask

1. Would different gender forms for words be considered grammatical gender or do we need a whole entire system for this to be considered? Is "confidante" an equivalent for "confidant?" Is this consideres conjugation/agreement? Why or why not? Is "Actress" a distinct word from "Actor?"
2. Do you believe words in English have a sort of de-facto gender system based on societal stereotypes, do you think this matters, should this system be soldified or eradicated? (or hypothetically, could we create a conhesive gender system with the language have now.)
3. How do you feel about gender in languages? Do these stereotypes exist in other languages, even languages with grammatial gender? Do you think all these things affect the way we experience the world.

Comment: It sounds like you're ready to read Robin Lakoff's book _Language and Women's Place_. It's old but it deals with your issues and it started a tradition of academic study of gender (in the social sense) and language. Gender in the linguistic sense is often confused with noun classes and classifier systems, which sometimes use gender terms but don't really have to do with social or physical gender.

Comment: @jlawler Thank you, I had all these ideas about gender that I needed to get out. For a language without grammatical gender, gender connotations in English frustrate and confuse me the most. Thanks for the response.

Comment: I think that a distinction can be made between words like "mid**wife**", "lumber**jack**", or "waitr**ess**", which are gendered by etymology; and words like "mechanic" or "secretary", which are technically ungendered, but may carry gendered connotations due to lopsided demographics of these occupations.